# Create new record on other object. no errors showing in code but record is not getting created. please help

Tags: apex, trigger

**Class**

```
public class attandenceclass {
    public static void attandance(list <Admission__c> admin){
        list<Attandance__c> attan = new list<Attandance__c>();
        for(Admission__c i :admin ){
            if(i.Name != null){
                Attandance__c j = new Attandance__c();
                i.Name = j.Name;
                attan.add(j);
            }
        }
        insert attan;
    }
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger attandance on Admission__c (before insert) {
    attandenceclass.attandance(Trigger.new);
}
```

Comment: Is `Admission__c:Name` an auto-number?

Comment: Try to use Database.SaveResult to confirm that new record is inserted or not. Helpful link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Comment: No, Admission__c:Name  is text.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `i.Name = j.Name;` be `j.Name = i.Name;`. I am assuming you are not populating anything. Also, I would use more descriptive names for easy identification if the code becomes larger.